# How to insert cell values into a sentence in excel with formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is an excel table, which looks like this:

Day | Month |   Year
1   |  Jan  |    1999
6   | no month     |   2009

How can I insert cell values into a sentence like this?
Scenario 1: "The person was born on" 1 "in the month of" Jan "in the year of" 1999

But if there is no month specified, the sentence should look like this:

Scenario 2: "The person was born on" 6 "without month specified" "in the year of" 2009

When the sentence is created, how can I separate the sentence into 3 different columns like this:

Column 1: "The person was born on" 6

Column2: "in the month of" Jan

Column 3: "in the year of" 1999

I have tried some functions but I could not come up with a solution that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sentence Creation with Dates

[Workbook Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtvsmlgsnea0zg5/how-to-insert-cell-values-into-a-sentence-in-excel-with-formulas_55318537.xlsx?dl=0) (Dropbox)

### In Cells:

**D2**

```
="The person was born "&IF(A2="","without day specified ","on the "&A2&CHOOSE(IF(AND(A2>10,A2<14),4,IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1))>0,VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1))<4),VALUE(RIGHT(A2,1)),4)),"st","nd","rd","th"))
```

**E2**

```
=IF(B2="","without month specified",IF(A2="","in","of")&" the month of " & B2)
```

**F2**

```
=IF(C2="","without year specified","in the year of "&C2)
```

**G2**

```
=D2&" "&E2&" "&F2&"."
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table starts from cell A1, enter the following into the cells specified.

Cell **D2**

```
="The person was born on " & A2
```

Cell **E2**

```
=IF(B2="","without month specified","in the month of " & B2)
```

Cell **F2**

```
="in the year of " & C2
```

Cell **G2**

```
=D2 & " " & E2 & " " & F2
```

... now fill all of those columns down to the last row of your table and you have your result.

Comment: If OP has `TEXTJOIN()`, `G2` can be `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,D2:F2)`.

Comment: @BruceWayne very true. Sound suggestion, I always overlook that because my version lacks it.

Comment: @BrightNess if it works for you, be sure to flag it as the answer, thanks.